# Is it a good idea to mess up with consts?

Tags: c++

As you know, static arrays are much faster than dynamic. C++ allows you to set the size of a static array like:

```
const unsigned int size = 5;
unsigned int data[size];
```

Now, I heard it's possible to change the value of the const.

a) First of all how to change the value of the const?

b) If I do the following:

```
const unsigned int size = 5;
somehow change the value of size to 65
unsigned int data[size];
```

What I lose? Seems too good to be true?

Comment: Modifying `const` data is *undefined behaviour*. So you cannot rely on a program that does it. It is not a good idea to write unreliable programs, so it is not a good idea to "mess up" with consts.

Comment: *"I heard it's possible to change the value of the const."* That's called hearsay. :)

Comment: BUT those people do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583076/c-c-changing-the-value-of-a-const

Comment: @Luka First comment on that question: "Even if you get it to compile. it is undefined behavior."

Comment: Even if you can change the value of the const, the size of the array is determined during compilation. It will be fixed.

Comment: "As you know, static arrays are much faster than dynamic." -- do we? Can you elaborate what exactly you mean by static and dynamic arrays and *how* one is faster than the other?

Comment: I mean the array I posted above is MUCH faster than malloc or vectors, I have tested this. It's faster because it doesn't waste time allocating memory I guess.

Comment: Ah, so you man faster to allocate. Yes, that's true, just not very interesting most of the time: Often, allocation speed is not the bottleneck, or you *can't* use stack allocation, or you don't need to allocate at all because you already have some allocation lying around.

Comment: "As you know" followed by something extremely questionable...

Comment: C'mon, don't down vote my question because of this

Comment: You should note that the whole endeavor is somewhat pointless. Constants are a tool to make code more human intellegible (so you can read "size" instead of some obscure and maybe ambiguous number). If you want a size of 65, then give your constant that value. Don't try to be super smart and cheat the compiler. There's nothing to be gained, even if it accidentially "works".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/583104/210905)) but result will be pretty undefined. This constant will be inlined in many places by compiler, that's why resulting code will be fast. 
So you'll see `size = 65` in some places and `size = 5` in others.